# How to fix "cannot establish connection, receiving end does not exist"?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I send a message from background script to popup .js I get an error `receiving end does not exist`. I also tried chrome.tabs.sendmessage and chrome.tabs.onupdate but nothing works.

Background.js

```js
set_badge();
setInterval(function () {
  set_badge();
}, 300000);

function set_badge() {
  settings = "";
  chrome.storage.sync.get("settings", function (result) {
    settings = result.settings;
    var url = "https://domaintube.net/json-example1.php?sessiondis=1234," + settings;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: data["message"].length.toString()});
        var myAudio = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL("clearly.mp3"));
        myAudio.play();
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({todo: "fetch"}, function () {
          alert("working");
        });
      });
  });
}
```

popup js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.todo == "fetch") {
    alert("Working");
    get_message();
  }
});

function get_message() {
  settings = "";
  chrome.storage.sync.get("settings", function (result) {
    settings = result.settings;
    var url = "https://domaintube.net/json-example1.php?sessiondis=1234," + settings;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(message => {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: message["message"].length.toString()});
        for (var i = 0; i < message["message"].length; i++) {
          $(".message").append("<h4>" + message["message"][i]["title"] + "</h4>");
          $(".message").append("<p>" + message["message"][i]["description"] + "</p>");
          $(".message")
            .append("<a href=" + message["message"][i]["url"] + " target='_blank'>" +
                    message["message"][i]["url"] + "</a>");
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: The popup doesn't run when it's closed so it can't receive messages. Only when it's open it can receive messages. You'll have to rework your extension - for example send a message from the popup and respond with the data in your background script. See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Actually the requirement is to fetch data every 5 minutes so if i fetch data without message it change badge every 5 min but when i open popup its shows current time message which may vary to numbers on badges so how message from popup will use to fetch after 5 mins when badge sets?

Comment: Save the result in chrome.storage.local, then your popup script can read it directly (without messaging) see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) and [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:storage).